# Facial Keypoints Detection using Softmax Regression

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision, softmax, kaggle

I am trying to build a basic Softmax Regression model using Tensorflow for [Kaggle Facial Keypoints Detection competition](https://www.kaggle.com/c/facial-keypoints-detection).

I followed Tensorflow beginner MNIST example for Softmax Regression model and Daniel Nouri's [blog](http://danielnouri.org/notes/2014/12/17/using-convolutional-neural-nets-to-detect-facial-keypoints-tutorial/) for data structuring.

The issue which I am facing is that the script always predicts **accuracy as 0.0**.

I also followed similar questions but with no luck :-

- [TensorFlow - why doesn't this sofmax regression learn anything?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33883382/tensorflow-why-doesnt-this-sofmax-regression-learn-anything?rq=1)
- [Why does TensorFlow example fail when increasing batch size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33641799/why-does-tensorflow-example-fail-when-increasing-batch-size?lq=1)

*Note :- I am dropping all rows from dataset which have missing values in them.*

```
import random
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import cross_validation

import tensorflow as tf

data = pd.read_csv("../data/training.csv")

data = data.dropna() # drop all rows that have missing values

# The Image column has pixel values separated by space; convert the values
# to numpy arrays:
data['Image'] = data['Image'].apply(lambda im: np.fromstring(im, sep=' '))

X = np.vstack(data['Image'].values)
X = X.astype(np.float32)
# convert from [0, 255] => [0.0, 1.0]
X = np.divide(X, 255.0)

print "X.shape == {}; X.min == {:.3f}; X.max == {:.3f}".format(
    X.shape, X.min(), X.max())


y = data[data.columns[:-1]].values
y = (y - 48) / 48  # scale target coordinates to [-1, 1]
y = y.astype(np.float32)

print "y.shape == {}; y.min == {:.3f}; y.max == {:.3f}".format(
    y.shape, y.min(), y.max())


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(X, y,
                                                                     test_size=0.2, random_state=42)


# serve data by batches

epochs_completed = 0
index_in_epoch = 0
num_examples = X_train.shape[0]


def next_batch(batch_size):

    global X_train
    global y_train
    global index_in_epoch
    global epochs_completed

    start = index_in_epoch
    index_in_epoch += batch_size
    if index_in_epoch > num_examples:
        # finished epoch
        epochs_completed += 1
        # shuffle the data
        perm = np.arange(num_examples)
        np.random.shuffle(perm)
        X_train = X_train[perm]
        y_train = y_train[perm]
        # start next epoch
        start = 0
        index_in_epoch = batch_size
        assert batch_size <= num_examples
    end = index_in_epoch
    return X_train[start:end], y_train[start:end]


def tf_softmax(output=True):
    random.seed(42)

    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 9216])

    W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([9216, 30]))
    b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([30]))

    y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) + b)

    y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 30])
    cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_mean(y_ * tf.log(y))
    cross_entropy = tf.Print(cross_entropy, [cross_entropy], "CrossE")

    train_step = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(0.01).minimize(cross_entropy)

    init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

    sess = tf.Session()
    sess.run(init)

    for i in range(1000):
        batch_xs, batch_ys = next_batch(100)
        sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})

    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))

    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float"))

    print sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: X_test, y_: y_test})


# Standard boilerplate to call the main() function to begin the program.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    tf_softmax()
```

**Terminal logs :**

```
X.shape == (2140, 9216); X.min == 0.000; X.max == 1.000
y.shape == (2140, 30); y.min == -0.920; y.max == 0.996
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/local_device.cc:40] Local device intra op parallelism threads: 8
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/direct_session.cc:58] Direct session inter op parallelism threads: 8
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] CrossE[-0.026783023]
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] CrossE[-0.746333]
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] CrossE[-1.5569628]
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] CrossE[-2.3121257]
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] CrossE[-3.1212008]
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] CrossE[-3.6717496]
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] CrossE[-4.5370874]
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] CrossE[-5.3017216]
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] CrossE[-6.0262742]
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] CrossE[-6.9303608]
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] CrossE[-7.3321404]
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] CrossE[-8.2394152]
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] CrossE[-inf]
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] CrossE[nan]
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] CrossE[nan]
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] CrossE[nan]
.....
.....
.....
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] CrossE[nan]
0.0
```

**EDIT :**

Seems like the issue is with the cost/cross_entropy, changing it to following fixed the issue :

```
cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(y_*tf.log(y + 1e-10))
```

Comment: What about logistic regression in sklearn? Have you tried that?

Comment: No i didnt tried that as i am trying to learn tensorflow.

Comment: Also solution mentioned in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34364526/3419997) seems to give justification to my issue. I will still wait for other valuable answers.